# Idea fails to detect imported scala library in java project

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea, import

I am currently working in a Java project, but need functionality from a Scala library. I added the Scala library, called factorie, as an external library.

[image: factorie is in external libraries]

I also added it as a dependency for the modules that need it.
[image: cannot resolve symbol on import]

However, IntelliJ Idea cannot find the library when attempting to import it, and will give a 'cannot resolve symbol'-error highlight and at compilation time.

To solve the problem I have tried adding the Scala SDK as a dependency to these modules, as well as resetting the caches.

Both the Java project and the Scala project are fairly big projects that I edited locally. They both use Maven poms that I have not edited.

So, in a nutshell: how can I ensure that Idea can detect my external Scala library?

Comment: Not sure if you're using maven, but if you are did you add the dependency to your project pom file?

Comment: Thanks for you comment. It was automatically added to the pom by Idea, but it did show the true name was not factorie, but cc.factorie. From that information I could make it work, so thank you for your comment: it saved my day!